# Using PythonTeX under windows

Tags: packages

I have a real big Problem:
I try to run PythonTeX but it doesn't work. All I get are question marks when using 
`\pygment{latex}{\py}` in my text.
I think the mistake is that PythonTeX is not linked with my latex - or with Python. But I do not know how and where I have do to this.

What I have done:
Installed Python 2.76,   Pygments and then PythonTeX.
I use TeX Live 2013.

Thanks for all help
Overlord

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you run LaTeX, then `pythontex.py` (or `pythontex.exe`), then LaTeX again?  That sounds like what happens before the Python script side of things has been run.

Comment: Yes i run Latex (TeX Live 2013) then pythontex2.pyc then LaTex again
I did not have Latex and pythontex2 in the the same folder. And the pdf file is in another direction. Can this be the problem? in TexLive I have this entry:
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex  -shell-escape filename.tex

Comment: PythonTeX doesn't require `-shell-escape`, but it won't cause problems.  You want something like `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex`, then `pythontex file.tex`, then `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode file.tex`.  The middle stage may need to be modified depending on your OS, and if you have wrappers/symlinks for `pythontex.py`.  The directories shouldn't be an issue.  Did you install PythonTeX using the TeX Live package manager?  It should set everything up automatically.

Comment: Thank you. but It will not work. I run the example pythontext quickstart (from the package) and there are no red mistakes-only blue ones: Non-existent Pygments content
My system is win 8.1
how should I there modify the middle stage?

I have installed it by using Tex Live package manager. 


Overlord

Comment: If you are under Windows with TeX Live, then you shouldn't need to modify anything from the example above.  What do you get from `pythontex --version` on the command line?  If you get the current version, everything should be installed and working correctly.